# Как сделать "обратное" древо на php/css?

Tags: php, дерево

Нашел исходники, как сделать вот такое дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрутил к нему добавление всех данных из базы стандартным подходом
http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/tree.php

Понимаю, что это не лучшая реализация, но суть не в ней.

Дерево у меня растет сверху вниз, от одного родителя могут ветвиться несколько детей. А мне надо наоборот. Родителей-то должно быть двое. Возможно ли как-то сделать такое дерево?

Comment: Что заставляет вас строить дерево от потомков к родителям? Пример, кстати, для начала абсолютно нормальный.

Comment: Потому что в приведенном примере дерево строится ОТ РОДИТЕЛЯ. А мне нужно ОТ РОДИТЕЛЕЙ. От двоих, а не от одного.

Comment: Такая реализация называется не деревом, а сетью.